# Doing a COUNT(*) GROUP BY based on a ManyToMany relation using DQL?

Tags: php, doctrine, dql

I have two entities <kbd>Person</kbd> and <kbd>Skill</kbd>, where a <kbd>Person</kbd> may have multiple skills.

<kbd>Person</kbd>

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PersonRepository")
 */
class Person
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Skill", inversedBy="people")
     */
    private $skills = [];

    // other fields and getters/setters
}
```

<kbd>Skill</kbd>

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SkillRepository")
 */
class Skill
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Person", mappedBy="skills")
     */
    private $people = [];

    // other fields and getters/setters
}
```

I have a form where I can filter people by skills, each skill is a checkbox and I want the number of people having that skill along with the checkbox's label.

The result is that:

[image: what i have]

I got it working using the following native query:

```
SELECT s.id, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM skill s
JOIN person_skill ps   /* table required by the M2M relation between person and skill */
ON s.id = ps.skill_id
GROUP BY s.id
```

As you can see, I require a JOIN on the ManyToMany table in order to get those counts.

How could I do this using Doctrine's DQL instead of using a native query?

Answer (score 1):

Actually when mapping entities with relations, Doctrine uses a custom object named [ArrayCollection](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/collections/latest/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.html).

It comes with many methods, such as filter() and count().

You can add a method to your skill entity if you want that would use the count method of the ArrayCollection (people).

To make sure you use the ArrayCollection properly you'll have to change your Skill class like this:

```
class Skill
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Person", mappedBy="skills")
     */
    private $people; //<-- Removed the default array definition

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->people = new ArrayCollection(); //Add this line in your constructor
    }

    public function countPeople()
    {
        return $this->people->count(); //Will return the number of people joined to the skill
    }

    // other fields and getters/setters
}
```

Comment: `->filter` on an ArrayCollection requires to load the entire table first. It won't scale :-). Thanks anyway

Comment: I understand the scalability issue. I read a bit more on associations and wanted to share [Extra Lazy Loading](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html) with you. With that enabled you could use the count function (no need of filter) without loading the collection. Although, it depends on how much you intend to use this association in your application. Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks for the information :) Looks less hacky than my solution! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Allright, I found the solution:

```
$rows = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder('s')
                  ->select('s.id, COUNT(p.id) AS c')
                  ->from(Skill::class, 's')
                  ->join('s.people', 'p')
                  ->groupBy('s.id')
                  ->getQuery()
                  ->getArrayResult();
```

It generates the following query:

```
SELECT s0_.id AS id_0, COUNT(p1_.id) AS sclr_1 
FROM skill s0_ 
INNER JOIN person_skill p2_
ON s0_.id = p2_.skill_id 
INNER JOIN person p1_ 
ON p1_.id = p2_.person_id 
GROUP BY s0_.id
```